# Why is Apache success page on my laptop?

Tags: mac, apache-http-server

At a hotel, I was first able to log into their wi-fi.  Wi-fi continually disconnected, but would reconnect when I called their IT.

Later, I opened my laptop and the page had APACHE SUCCESSFULLY INSTALLED.

What is this?

Comment: What was the url?
What's your pcs operating system?

Comment: I'm gonna say this has nothing to do with your ex's obsession

Comment: If he's rich, does he want to adopt? :-)

Comment: Please! If only he would transfer his obsession to adopting you I would never have another computer issue. :)

Comment: Operating System is Mac 10.9

Comment: Have found Kext/log installed previously. As well as Bit torrent.

Answer (score 0):

This the page displayed by default once the Apache web server is installed. Hotel wifi usually redirects to their login page, but it seems there should be something wrong there and hence you are redirected to the default page. The network guys over at the hotel might be trying to fix something. They might ended somehow redirecting to this.

A good thing would be to ask the management if there is anything wrong with the network...

Comment: Thank you.  I was never able to connect again after Apache was some how loaded.  Further, I was unable to use a hotspot via cell phone.

Comment: Have found OSX Log/Kext -A

Comment: Well... the problem is with their network most probably. I don't think using a different device will solve the issue. Apache is running on their web server that was supposed to present you with a login page or some portal of some sort. My guess is that the web application they're using is offline.

Comment: Thank you so much.  Due to previous spyware and chronic manipulation of my networks ...  I need and enjoy checking with experts like you :)

Comment: @AmyMalcolm I am not that good really. I am just a Linux enthusiast who enjoys these things. Thanks for the compliment though. I hope I was of help. :)